# Integration with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to calculate integral of Deep Neural Network with respect to input and use it in my loss function.

I tried two different scheme.
First, I used tf.gradients to go around the problem. (this method leads to noisy function approximation)
Second, I used tf.integral but it is not what I am looking for.

```py
x_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
y_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None,1])
y_pred = mlp(x_ph)

def multilayer_perceptron(x,weights, biases):
    # *********************** Hidden layer 1 ***********************#
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])


    return tf.reshape(tf.convert_to_tensor(tf.gradients(layer_1, y)),(-1,1)), layer_1
# I want to have my ouput as return layer_1, integral(layer_1,x)

def cost(x, y, z):
    jx, fx = multilayer_perceptron(x,weights, biases, kp)
    fx = tf.reshape(fx, (-1,1))
    jx =  tf.reshape(jx, (-1,1))
    cost_ = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(fx-y)) + tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(jx-z))


    return cost_
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution. I defined an extra placeholder t and used it to calculate the value of integral at x.

https://github.com/moradza/Practice-and-Test/blob/master/Anti%20derivative%20calculator%20of%20Tensorflow%20network%201D%20input.ipynb to see the code.